# CasperJS: continue operation after waitForSelector() failure

Tags: casperjs

I have a waitForSelector() that fails in 1/5 times due to some target-side JS sometimes loading after 5000ms, which causes Casper to stop operation.

How can I make casper continue operating if a waitForSelector() fails?

Answer (score 2):

`waitForSelector` takes an `onTimeout` parameter, which if provided prevents the script from throwing an error.

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap it in a try catch.

```
try {

    do the code that you need it to do. 

}

catch (err) {

    optional code if it fails. 

}
```